# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time,

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

when I try to add migration I'm getting this error. I have also implemented EntityFrameworkCore.Design and Tools. And I checked other questions but none of them is working for me.

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly IDateTimeService _dateTime;
        private readonly IAuthenticatedUserService _authenticatedUser;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IDateTimeService dateTime, IAuthenticatedUserService authenticatedUser) : base(options)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            _dateTime = dateTime;
            _authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;
        }
        public DbSet<Quiz> Quizzes { get; set; }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableBaseEntity>())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.NowUtc;
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _authenticatedUser.UserId;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.Entity.LastModified = _dateTime.NowUtc;
                        entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _authenticatedUser.UserId;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Could you help me to fix this problem and add a migration

Answer (score 0):

Inside the asp.net core, if you have used the default identity and you want to customsize it, I suggest you could try to use the IdentityDbContext instead of using the IdentityDbContext.

Like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sutd> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Besides, for troubleshooting the EF migration issue, I suggest you could refer to below codes:

```
add-migration test -verbose
```